# evm_revert to snapshot#1 in ganache-cli automatically

Tags: ganache, truffle-test

I am using `evm_increaseTime` in my tests to move block time but in `ganache-cli` it shows that it is reverting to snapshot #1.
 I have not used `evm_revert` or `evm_snapshot`.

- Is it normal?
- what is the reason behind it?

Comment: If you're using Truffle test suite then yes - at the end of each test (or possibly at the beginning of each test), it calls `evm_revert`. You can open Truffle source code and view it for yourself (where you can also disable it if you're interested).